# Can I replace 11 speed 11-40t with a 11-42t or 11-46t staying with Shimano XT family?

Tags: chain, cassette, drivetrain, freewheel

Can I replace the 11 speed 11-40t cassette with a 11-42t or 11-46t? What other parts will be needed to complete job? I.e. new chain, long chain, spacers?

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what derailleur and front rings you have.

The current [Deore XT M8000 GS](http://bike.shimano.com/content/sac-bike/en/home/components11/mountain/deore-xt-m8000.html) (which we can probably assume you have) specs say:

- Max 11-42T cassette for a 2x11 setup
- Max 11-46T cassette for a 1x11 setup

Additionally for a 2x11 setup there is a max 10 teeth difference between the front rings.

Comment: i have a 30 t front ring   running 1x11.  thanks